# How to install Mono in AIX?

Tags: software-installation, aix, mono

I don't have root access to an AIX 5.2 machine and want to run Mono programs in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mono does not support AIX.

If you want to try to port Mono to AIX, you would probably want to:

- Turn on the manual checking of dereferences in Mono, as AIX keeps the page at address zero mapped, preventing a whole class of errors from being caught.   I forget the name of the define, but it was introduced some six months ago.
- You would have to make sure that your signal handlers work, and that exception unwinding works on your platform.

The rest is probably replacing a few Posix functions with some AIX equivalents, but if you get the two above working, you would likely have a working Mono installation.   But neither one of those tasks is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Just compile from sources and install it into you home directory with `./configure --prefix=$HOME; make; make install`.  This way you don't need root access at any step.

To run .net assemblies with your compiled version of mono run `~/bin/mono program.exe` or add `~/bin` to your `PATH` and just use `mono program.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** my answer is about "how to install Mono without root access". Clearly Miguel's answer about Mono not working on AIX makes the rest moot.

Alex is right, you can install in your home directory.

Full instructions for installing Mono outside of /usr are available here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Following these instructions is helpful if, for example, somebody installed Mono in /usr later on but you wanted to keep using your version.